# shell script to replace a keyword in a file with the contents of another file

Tags: shell, sed, find-and-replace, sh

I'm to create a .sh to replace a specific keyword in a file using the contents of an other file.

- template.html contains a unique string "**PLACEHOLDER**"
- it must be replaced with the contents of file "contents.html"

Sed can be used to replace the keyword:

```
value="hello superuser"
sed -e "s/__PLACEHOLDER__/${value}/g" template.html > page.html
```

So I tried the following:

```
value=$(<contents.html)
sed -e "s/__PLACEHOLDER__/${value}/g" template.html > page.html
```

And get the following error message:
unescaped newline inside substitute pattern

How to handle this sort of situation please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With bash, you could write:

```
templ=$(<template.html)
value=$(<contents.html)
echo "${templ//__PLACEHOLDER__/$value}" > page.html
```

Comment: $value is not escaped, so if it contains / or } it will fail

Comment: Not true: `tmpl="foo__PLACEHOLDER__bar"; value='with/and}too'; echo "${tmpl//__PLACEHOLDER__/$value}"` works as expected

Answer (score 1):

This is because "contents.html" contains multiple lines, and the newline characters have to be converted into `\n` before feeding to `sed`.

For example if "contents.html" contains

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

You will need to change it to `Line 1\nLine2\nLine3" before using it as the substitute pattern.

I changed your script as:

```
value=$(sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' contents.html)
sed -e "s/__PLACEHOLDER__/${value}/g" template.html > page.html
```

The first line reads "contents.html" and replace newline character with `\n`.  (Credit to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n))